# How to stop program to wait user action?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a method which make move on click

```
public void processMove(int fromX, int fromY, int toX, int toY) {
    ...
    if (moveCorrect()) {
        makeMove(fromX, fromY, toX, toY);
    }
    ...
}
```

This method called from handler of mouse clicks, added to the certain JPanel. This logic works fine until I found out that pawns can be transformed if they reaches last line. So I should show overlay in which user will choose piece to which pawn will be transformed. So I call PawnTransformOverlay.

```
if (//if pawn reaches last line) {
    PawnTransfromOverlay.showOverlay();
}
```

I actually would like to stop the program until user will click, get clicked piece from overlay and transform pawn without leaving this `if` statement. The only option I can come up with right now is to make handler for PawnTransformOverlay and call some function, like `transformPawn()` from this handler on click. But then I will have to copy these `fromX, fromY, toX, toY` to use them from  `transformPawn()`. It seems to be better way I don't know about.

Is it possible, or there is some other ways to do it better? Every ideas and tips will be really helpful!!!

To better understanding what I'm trying to ask:
https://github.com/Yonshoku/Chess2

And link to the class where I can't figure out right way to do:
https://github.com/Yonshoku/Chess2/blob/master/src/chessgui/Game.java

Comment: Use a [modal JDialog](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) to ask the user which piece to promote the pawn.

Comment: Even It's simple and trivial answer, this is exaclty what I needed and I actually never would think about it. Thank you very much!!! @GilbertLeBlanc

Comment: @Yokoton make sure that selection is valid e.g. what happens if the user closes the modal window with X and does not select the figure to promote from pawn?

Comment: Thank you, of course it have cases to check, It's easy thing for now! @KarolDowbecki